# Elm : Decode Http.Error

Tags: elm

I'm wondering how to decode an Http.Error in elm and store it's data on my model.

I know that the error response is going to return this structure.

```
{
  error: "Some error message",
  ok: false
}
```

Here are my models and my Http request

```
type alias Model =
  { url = String
  , result : String
  , errorMessage : String
  , error : Bool
  }

model : Model
model =
  { url = ""
  , result = ""
  , errorMessage = ""
  , error = False
  }

-- make the request

makeRequest : String -> Cmd Msg
makeRequest url =
  Task.perform FetchFail FetchSucceed (Http.get decodeTitle url)

-- decode the success response

decodeTitle : Json.Decoder String
decodeTitle =
  Json.at ["title"] Json.string

-- decode the error

decodeError =
  Json.object2 User
    ("error" := Json.string)
    ("ok" := Json.bool)
```

I was hoping I could handle this in `FetchFail` of my update like so.

```
type Msg
  = FetchTitle
  | FetchSucceed String
  | FetchFail Http.Error


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update action model =
  case action of
    ...

    FetchFail err ->
      let
        error =
          decodeError error
      in
        ({ model | ok = error.ok, errorMessage = error.error}, Cmd.none)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `Error` type alias seems unused. Better remove it (from the question if it was used elsewhere).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Elm 0.17:**

The Http.Error type is a union type that can hold the the response code if there was any.

> type Error
>      = Timeout
>      | NetworkError
>      | UnexpectedPayload String
>      | BadResponse Int String

You can `case` over the err variable to access it.

```
FetchFail err ->
  case err of
    BadResponse code error ->
      -- handle error message
    _ ->
      -- other error
```

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/3.0.1/Http#Error

---

With **elm 0.18** and the transition to [elm-lang/http](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/1.0.0/Http#Error) the **Error** type has been modified:

```
type Error
    = BadUrl String
    | Timeout
    | NetworkError
    | BadStatus (Response String)
    | BadPayload String (Response String)
```

Comment: I get ```Cannot find pattern `BadResponse`

20|     BadResponse code error -> error
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: In Elm 0.17 [evancz/elm-http](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/3.0.1/Http) was used. Since Elm 0.18 [elm-lang/http](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/1.0.0/Http) is the default. The new module has different types. See [Http.Error](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/1.0.0/Http#Error)

Comment: thanks, I've updated your answer since it is the first result I get when I search for this error :-)